# "Value does not fall within the expected range." when trying to call a method on a COM object using c#

Tags: c#, com-interop

I get an exception when trying to call a method on a COM object using c#.

This only happens when I try to call the method without using the COM runtime callable wrapper (RCW) interop assembly generated by tlbimp.exe.

When strictly using the COM interop assembly, everything works perfectly.

The reason I don't want to use the COM interop assembly is because the CLSIDs and ProgIDs may be different on the target machine than when the interop assembly is created, but the method names, definitions, and structures are the same.

In this test, however, the COM server is registered using the same CLSIDs and ProgIDs as those defined in the runtime callable wrapper (RCW) which was directly generated from the running COM server assembly.

Running on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.
C++ COM server is 32-bit
C# assembly is built using "Any CPU" and targets .NET Framework 4

C++ COM server IDL code snippet:

```
[
object,
uuid(MyComObjectInterfaceGuid),
dual,
helpstring("MyComObject Interface"),
pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyComObject : IDispatch
{
    #import "MyCustomStruct.h"
    [id(110), helpstring("Method110")] HRESULT Method110([out] MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT *pMyCustomStruct);
}

[
uuid(MyComObjectGuid),
helpstring("MyComObject")
]
coclass MyComObject
{
    [default] interface IMyComObject;
};
```

MyCustomStruct.h:

```
#define MyCustomType2 MyCustomType;
#define long unsigned MyCustomType2;

typedef struct MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT
{
    bool            property1;
    MyCustomType    property2;
    wchar_t         property3[42];
    int             property4;
} MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT;
```

When the COM server DLL is registered, the rgs file inserts the ProgId registry values for example.

The runtime callable wrapper produces the following structure:

```
public struct MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT
{
    public byte property1;
    public MyCustomType property2;
    public ushort[] property3;
    public int property4;
}

public struct MyCustomType
{
    public uint @value;
}
```

C# code snippet that works:

```
using MyComObjectInteropNamespace;

MyComObject myComObject = new MyComObject();

MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT myCustomStruct = new MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT();
myComObject.Method110(out myCustomStruct);

// myCustomStruct contains the expected values
```

C# code snippet that throws an exception:

```
using MyComObjectInteropNamespace;

Type myComObjectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Company.Product.MyComObject", true);
object myComObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myComObjectType);

MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT myCustomStruct = new MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT();
object[] args = { myCustomStruct };

ParameterModifier parameterModifier = new ParameterModifier(1);
parameterModifier[0] = true;
ParameterModifier[] parameterModifiers = { parameterModifier };

myComObjectType.InvokeMember( // exception is thrown here
    "Method110",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    myComObject,
    args,
    parameterModifiers,
    null,
    null);

// code does not get this far
myCustomStruct = (MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT)args[0];
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
       at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
  InnerException:
```

C# code snippet that also throws the same exception:

```
using MyComObjectInteropNamespace;

Type myComObjectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Company.Product.MyComObject", true);
object myComObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myComObjectType);

object[] args = { new UnknownWrapper(null) };

ParameterModifier parameterModifier = new ParameterModifier(1);
parameterModifier[0] = true;
ParameterModifier[] parameterModifiers = { parameterModifier };

myComObjectType.InvokeMember( // exception is thrown here
    "Method110",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null,
    myComObject,
    args,
    parameterModifiers,
    null,
    null);

// code does not get this far
MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT myCustomStruct = (MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT)args[0];
```

C# code snippet that also throws an exception:

```
dynamic myComObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Company.Product.MyComObject", true));

MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT myCustomStruct = new MY_CUSTOM_STRUCT();
myComObject.Method110(out myCustomStruct); // exception is thrown here
```

Exception:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject(Object obj, IntPtr pDstNativeVariant)
       at System.Dynamic.UnsafeMethods.InitVariantForObject(Object obj, Variant& variant)
  InnerException: null
```

I've also posted on the MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72d56d0a-3ae3-4879-be33-eeda629c96e6/value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range-when-trying-to-call-a-method-on-a-com-object-using):

Comment: Set the length of your property3 in `C#` also to 42.

Comment: Thank you, @Snake.  I have tried that, such as "myCustomStruct.property3 = new ushort[42];", before invoking "Method110" but I get the same exception.